# Receiver (<ViewController>) has no segue with identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have no idea and have tried renaming the story board, cleaning the project, changing simulators. I cannot get my by segue to work.

I have a manual modeling segue from ViewController (A) to ViewController (B), called "MoveToLogin".

What happens is when you click the login button, I create a new instance of a custom object I made that contains a log in method like so:

```
#ViewController.m
//If the username and password fields are not blank, attempt to log in.
        [_custom object loginUser:_usernameTxt.text password:_passwordTxt.text]

#custom object's login method (CustomObject.m)
-(void)loginUser:(NSString *)username password:(NSString *)password
{
    ViewController *viewcontroller = [[ViewController alloc]init];

    //Attempts to log in the user
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    NSDictionary *params = @ {@"username" : username, @"password": password};
    [manager POST:_login_url parameters:params
    success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
    {
        if([responseObject objectForKey:@"login_okay"])
        {
            _valid_login = YES;
            [viewcontroller onSuccessfulLogin];
        }
        else
        {
            _valid_login = NO;
            [viewcontroller onInvalidLogin];
        }
    }
          failure:
     ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         [viewcontroller onRequestFail];
     }];
}
```

As you can see the custom object's method, which is in another class obviously, upon receiving a json response from the server calls ViewController (a) method onSuccessfulLogin.

That method looks like so:

```
-(void)onSuccessfulLogin
{
    //if we get a successful login
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MoveToLogin" sender:nil];
}
```

But whenever I successfully log in, I am presented with this pleasant message:

> terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'MoveToLogin''

Comment: You don't want to create a new view controller in your custom object, you want it to reference the already existing one that owns the custom object, either through delegates or passing a completion block to your login method.  The view controller you are performing the segue on is not the one that is currently on screen and was not correctly created from the storyboard using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` so it won't have the segue set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create an instance of `viewcontroller` like you are doing..  In general it is good to have your async methods use blocks/delegates.. 
How about doing something like this using a completion block..

```
    #ViewController.m
    //If the username and password fields are not blank, attempt to log in.
     [_customobject  loginUser:@"" password:@"" completionBlock:^(BOOL validLogin, NSError *error) {
        if(error){
            [self onRequestFail];
        }else{
            if(validLogin){
                    //if we get a successful login
                 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MoveToLogin" sender:nil];
            }else{
                //if we get a invalid login
            }
        }        
    }];

    #custom object's login method (CustomObject.m)
    -(void)loginUser:(NSString *)username password:(NSString *)password completionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL validLogin, NSError *error))completionblock{

        //Attempts to log in the user
        AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
        manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
        manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
        NSDictionary *params = @ {@"username" : username, @"password": password};
        [manager POST:_login_url parameters:params
        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
        {
            if([responseObject objectForKey:@"login_okay"])
            {
                _valid_login = YES;
                if (completionblock) completionblock(YES, nil);
            }
            else
            {
                _valid_login = NO;
                if (completionblock) completionblock(NO, nil);
            }
        }
              failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
             if (completionblock) completionblock(NO, error);
         }];
    }
```